# Mongodb or mongoose fetch all records from collection A into other aggregate query which is fetching B collection data

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Writing REST API using Nodejs and database is mongodb 3.6.

**Collections Names** : Subscription, Users and Offering

I am using aggregate function to fetch data from subscription and using lookup I am fetching user which has subscribed.

What I want is in the same output (previous line) I also want to list all the records from offering collection as array.

How do I can get it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your question makes no sense, am I missing something? where is the code? You need to provide us with a concrete example to work from. [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you can, and neither you should. Getting all records of some collection is bad practice, always try to limit yourself with only things you need.
If you really want to add resutls from some totally unrelated collection then you should make separate request and then add them together in json you sending to client.